# vim-snipmate not expanding non-source code file

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, snipmate

I am using snipmate for coding and it works fine.

However I would also like to use it on txt file extension, but this does not work at all.

Is it designed to work like that? How can I get snippet expansion on ad-hoc file types?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`*.txt` files have the `text` filetype but you probably don't have snippets for that filetype. You can create them in `~/.vim/snippets/text.snippets` and do the same for every filetype for which you don't have snippets.

Note that the snippets in `~/.vim/snippets/_.snippets` are "global" and thus available in any filetype.

If you want to expand JavaScript snippets in an HTML file, you can "combine" filetypes with `:set ft=html.javascript`.

Comment: Thanks romainl, it works now. My problem was that I had made a txt.snippet file, not text.snippet.

Comment: Yes, it's `<filetype>.snippets`, not `<extension>.snippets`.